# I have a vaio and my touchpad scroll doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, mouse-wheel

I have a VAIO windows 7 64 bit operating system. My scroll does not work for a while.I used to stroke the far-right edge of the touchpad for vertical scrolling and the bottom edge for horizontal but is doesn't work now.

I have downloaded and installed the latest driver for that but it didn't fix. I don't know why but I cannot open Control Panel>Mouse. As soon as run Mouse an error occurs and I have to close that.

This is the problem when I open Mouse in Control Panel :

[image]

Comment: Uninstall the driver, reboot and install it again?

Comment: I already have done that but did not work

Comment: After you've uninstalled the driver, were you able to open the Mouse properties page?

Comment: No. I couldn't open Mouse properties even when I have uninstalled the driver.